# How to disable password algorithm hashing in keycloak when importing users?

Tags: keycloak, bcrypt

I am trying to import passwords which are already hashed using BCrypt. I also need to import a list of users with their passwords.
Furthermore, the legacy system is using the same bcrypt process as the implemented (PasswordHashProvider) in Keycloak.

To sum up, the last step is to find how to import (with a json file) my users from my legacy system to Keycloak by skipping BCrypt.

Any ideas ?

Keycloak 6.0.1

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea for user migration. Moreover, bcrypt is a hashing algorithm (NOT encryption algorithm)

Comment: Could you please whisper a better idea ?

Comment: I don't know the keycloak functionalities. But, no one other than the end user should know the password (NOT even the system administrator). That's why one-way hashing algorithms like bcrypt are used. We cannot get back the original password from the hash. The above approach sounds like having a CSV file with all user passwords which is wrong (equivalent to not having passwords at all)

Comment: Passwords are unknown, I can only get hashed passwords, so I would like to insert them in Keycloak without having Keycloak to hash them twice.

Comment: Is the legacy system using the same bcrypt work factors as the new system?

Comment: Exaclty, it is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205302/discussion-between-defoncesko-and-saptarshi-basu).

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in a nice article
https://dev.to/carnewal/import-existing-users-with-bcrypt-hashed-passwords-in-keycloak-17oo

Basically, you add two jars needed for Keycloak that it needs to process bcrypt hashed passwords.

Then you make a request to the Keycloak admin API to add the user credentials, specifying bcrypt as the hashing algorithm.